# Parameters in the default function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There are tables `table1, table2:`

```
| ID  | amount |                | ID  | Code   |
+-----+--------+                +-----+--------+
| 1   |  302   |                | 1   | N418   |
| 41  |  54    |                | 41  | S479   |
| 1   |  344   |
```

The function should work like this
if the user has set id then we are looking for by id, if id is not set then the code should return the amount
**Code:**

```
create or replace function GetSum(p_id  in number,
                                  p_Cod in varchar2 default null)
  return number as
  nTotal number;
  vCod   varchar2;
begin
  select sum(t1.amount), t2.code
    into nTotal, vCod
    from table1 t1, table2 t2
   where t1.id = t2.id
     and t1.id = p_id

  return nTotal;
end GetSum;
```

How to make the user able to set one of two parameters to get the amount?

Answer (score 1):

is this what are you looking for?

note i have also changed the join syntax, do not use the old one.

```
create or replace function GetSum(p_id  in number,
                                  p_Cod in varchar2 default null) return number 
as
  nTotal number;
  vCod   varchar2(100); -- <- you should the size of your varchar
begin
  select sum(t1.amount), t2.code
    into nTotal, vCod
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id

   where p_id is null or t1.id = p_id
   ;  

   return nTotal;
end GetSum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Join, along with `OR` might help:

```
SQL> create or replace function getsum(p_id   in number,
  2                                    p_code in varchar2
  3                                   )
  4  return number
  5  is
  6    retval number;
  7  begin
  8    select sum(t1.amount)
  9      into retval
 10       from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
 11       where t2.id = p_id
 12          or t2.code = p_code;
 13
 14    return retval;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> select getsum(41, null) res1,
  2         getsum(null, 'S479') res2,
  3         --
  4         getsum(1, null) res3
  5  from dual;

      RES1       RES2       RES3
---------- ---------- ----------
        54         54        646

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the logic you describe:

```
select sum(t1.amount), t2.code
into nTotal, vCod
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where (t1.id = p_id) or
      (t2.code = p_cod and p_id is null);
```